# Search mechanism to include words as a whole

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, search

I have created a search mechanism that searches through an array of strings for an exact string match, however I want it to be a bit more intuitive.

I can also get it to search for a string within the string (for example `chicken` in `grilled chicken` - however the issue is this allows users to type `ken` or `ill` and it returns `grilled chicken`.

I would like it to return if I typed in `chicken` or `grilled`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to have a more intuitive search mechanism?

EDIT:

The correct answer below worked when typing 1 word and it would search all individual words in a string. However, I realised it fails when you search with 2 words (as it only searches each string word individually).

I solved this by adding `|| search == string` to the `if` to include not just individually word matches but whole string matches.

However I am still having an issue with it either searching for:

Whole string matches
OR
Matches with individual words.

This means it fails when `search = green cup` and `string = big green cup`. Is there a way to solve this by cutting for collections to search within? Perhaps something similar to:

`string.split(' ')` but to also include `big green, green cup` to the array also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try This Simplest Code without Regex**

```
var data = ["first string1 is here", "second string2 is here", "third string3 is here"];
    var wordToSearch = "string2 is thanks";
    var broken = wordToSearch.split(' ');
    var result = 'not found';
    if(broken.length == 1){
    data.forEach(function(d){
        d1 = d.split(' ');
    if(d1.includes(wordToSearch))
        result = d;
});
}
else if(broken.length == 2)
{
    data.forEach(function(d){
        var d1 = d.split(' ');
        if(d1.includes(broken[0]) && d1.includes(broken[1]))
        {
            result = d;
        }
    });
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Hi, I have just realised that this missed part of the functionality I am missing - can you help solve it? This indeed does a 1 word match for whole words in a string, however I want it to also search for the whole phrase (so return true if `wordToSearch = "first string1"`. With that, I would also like phrases with 3 words to match if 2 match (return true if `wordToSearch = "big cup"` `string = "green big cup"`

Comment: @JDT now check the edited answer above... now you can search by two words.

Comment: Does this solution work? Isn't `broken.length` actually 3 in this case?

Comment: your search criteria was about one-two words... so i designed according to your given criteria.

Comment: I know, I am saying in your example above you have `broken.length == 2` but isn't it actually 3?

Comment: actually you asked to match one word or two... if you want to compare exactly 3 words then we can do `broken.length == 3` and in IF condition we have to add `if(d1.includes(broken[0]) && d1.includes(broken[1]) && d1.includes(broken[2]))`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use RegExp with word boundary anchor - `\b`.

```
function search(query, arr) {
    var res  = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + query + '\\b');
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        if (re.test(item)) res.push(item);
    });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you only want to search by whole words, if that's the case, you could split the string by the space character and then search through the resultant array for matches.